# Pipeline build devops

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to deploy aspnetboilerplate with Azure DevOps Pipelines. I'm using the basic dotnet build -c release command, but always get:

```
   "d:\a\1\s\aspnet-core\src\Myapp.Web.Mvc\Myapp.Web.Mvc.csproj" (Build target) (1:7) ->
   "d:\a\1\s\aspnet-core\src\Myapp.Web.Core\Myapp.Web.Core.csproj" (default target) (2:6) ->
   "d:\a\1\s\aspnet-core\src\Myapp.EntityFrameworkCore\Myapp.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj" (default target) (5:7) ->
   (CoreCompile target) -> 
     C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(52,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Assembly with same name is already loaded Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [d:\a\1\s\aspnet-core\src\Myapp.EntityFrameworkCore\Myapp.EntityFrameworkCore.csproj]
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use publish command. go to the solution root directory and run

```
dotnet publish -c release -o C:\myproject
```

Comment: Thanks, i get an output with that, however it's full of .cs files, csproj files etc. Surely that's not right?